# Using cmd command "copy /b file0 + file1 + file2 newfile" is there an easy way to do this with 350 files?

Tags: cmd

Using cmd command

```
copy /b file.0 + file.1 + file.2 newfile
```

is there an easy way to do this with 350 files?

Comment: you can regex in your command

Comment: `Copy /b *.txt Newfile` see `copy /?`.

Answer (score 2):

According to `copy /?`, you can concatenate multiple source files by listing them explicitly with a `+` in between or by specifying a wildcard pattern:

```
copy /b file.* newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all files are numbered sequentially:

```
IF EXIST "newfile" (DEL "newfile")
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,349) DO (TYPE "file.%%i" >>"newfile")
```

On an interactive command line, use only one percent `%` character for the `i` variable.

If the files are not all numbered in this way or you need to account for missing files, please edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

U can use this, if all files are numbered sequentially :

```
FOR /L %i IN (0,1,1279) DO (TYPE "file_name%i" >>"new_file.extension_name")
```

or

```
FOR /L %i IN (0,1,1279) DO (TYPE "file_name.extension_name%i" >>"new_file.extension_name")
```

the "1279" can be replaced by any number of ur files, don't forget to open cmd in the file directory.